# How do I move files out of a broken directory in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal, putty

I know the premise of the question may be confusing, but I want to understand what happened.

Recently I have been experimenting with the rockchip **OK3399** single-chip computer(see [here](https://www.forlinx.net/product/rk3399-103.html)) and have installed a linux system on it with TF card installation. Using [Putty](https://www.putty.org/) and connecting with serial protocol, I was able to establish a connection with the **OK3399** computer and control it through my laptop.

I am trying to self-learn some linux with the **OK3399** system. I created a bash code by the name of `displayvids.sh` inside the directory `/usr/bin`, which is meant to take a variable number of pictures with a mipi camera and then save in a directory for work.

I finished writing the code, but for some reason I cannot run the `.sh` file when my working directory is not the `/usr/bin` directory, despite `/usr/bin` being in the `%PATH%` environment variable. So, I executed the following command:

`mv /usr/bin/display* /usr/local/bin`

... attempting to move the file to `/usr/local/bin` instead. The command ran successfully, but when I tried to run the command:

`cd /usr/local/bin`

It tells me that I cannot cd to bin

[image]

As seen from the above image, the `/usr/local/bin` is not even a directory. Why would mv succeed if the target was not a directory? How can I retrieve my bash file?

Comment: As the `/usr/local/bin` directory did not exist `mv` created a file with that name. `mv` it back, create the directory (`mkdir -p /usr/local/bin`) and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would mv succeed if the target was not a directory?

`mv` can also rename files:

```
mv foo.txt bar.txt
```

You renamed your script to `bin` and moved it under `/usr/local`.

You may want to remember to add a trailing slash next time, to have `mv` barf if the target isn't a directory:

```
mv /usr/bin/display* /usr/local/bin/
```

> How can I retrieve my bash file?

Rename it back.

```
mv bin displayvids.sh
```

---

For future reference, you can use the `file` command to (try to) identify the contents of a file, if it's installed:

```
file bin
```

would have probably said `bin: Bash script` or similar.